# regex not matching wildcard

Tags: java, regex

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr><td><font color="#306eff">P: </font>9283-1000<font color="#306eff">&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

OR (newline)

```
<tr><td><font color="#306eff">P: </font>9283-1000

<font color="#306eff">&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I went to regexpal.com and entered the following regex:

```
P: </font>(.*?)<font
```

And it matches. But when I do it in Java, it doesn't match:

```
    Pattern rP = Pattern.compile(">P: </font>(.*?)<font");
    Matcher mP = rP.matcher(data);

    if (mP.find()) {
        System.out.println(mP.group(1).trim());
    }
```

There are multiple regexes I tried on different occasions and they simply don't work in Java. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Java has it's own REGEX

Comment: [Use a HTML parser instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot does not match newline by default.

Use `Pattern rP = Pattern.compile(">P: </font>(.*?)<font", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

Answer (score 2):

Your works fine for me.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "<tr><td><font color=\"#306eff\">P: </font>9283-1000<font color=\"#306eff\">&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        Pattern rP = Pattern.compile(">P: </font>(.*?)<font");
        Matcher mP = rP.matcher(data);

        if (mP.find()) {
            System.out.println(mP.group(1).trim());
        }
    }
```

This prints: `9283-1000`.

I guess the problem may be in how `data` is fed into the program.
Because the code itself is OK as you can see from this output.

Comment: I updated the code. Input contains newline. That's why it's not matching. Can you tell me how to match that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead:

```
(?ims).*?>P: </font>(.*?)<font.+
```

---

**Sample code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data="<tr><td><font color=\"#306eff\">P: </font>9283-1000<font color=\"#306eff\">&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    Pattern rP = Pattern.compile("(?ims).*?>P: </font>(.*?)<font.+");
    Matcher mP = rP.matcher(data);

    if (mP.find()) {
          System.out.println(mP.group(1).trim());
    }
}
```

**Output**

> 9283-1000

Comment: @user2320462 Can you post the data you're using in your question ?

Comment: I updated my question. The input contains newlines. Can you tell me how to deal with that please? Thanks

Comment: Even if there is newlines, the regex works fine (the `s` flag is activated). Check your code then...

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
String data="<tr><td><font color=\"#306eff\">P: </font>9283-1000<font color=\"#306eff\">&nbsp;&nbsp;";
Pattern rP = Pattern.compile(">P: </font>(.*?)<font");
Matcher mP = rP.matcher(data);

if (mP.find()) {
      System.out.println(mP.group(1).trim());
}
```

In java only difference is in escape character .

Comment: sorry, I don't see the difference

Comment: Difference is in data  variable . In java string characters must be between  "" . In your html code double quotes are there. So you want to escape those charaters using escape character \ .